# Kotlin. Get string part out of array of bytes

Tags: arrays, string, kotlin

From a bluetooth device I get data in an array of bytes. 20 bytes are reserved for a string the other bytes contain data like short and int values.
The bytes for the string are converted to a string using Charset.UTF_8 (or US_ASCII). The problem is I can not get ride of the part that contains ordinary zero's like in other languages as c, c# and c++. Tried droplast after determining the first zero character. Nothing works. What am I missing.
The piece of code is this:

```
            val bytes = job.characteristic.value
            var index = 0;
            var tempBytes = ByteArray(30)
            while(index < 20) {
                if (bytes[index] != 0.toByte())
                    tempBytes[index] = bytes[index]
                else
                    break
                ++index
            }
            val newString = tempBytes.toString(Charsets.ISO_8859_1).dropLast(20 - index)
            Log.i("BleDeviceVM", "Received for newString: " + newString)
```

Outcome in Android Studio is like this:
I/BleDeviceVM:
Received for newString: LEDServer��������������������

instead of:
LEDServer

**Thanks Broot.
Coming from c, c#, some c++ and some Java Kotlin is a bit confusing at first.This piece of code works fine I think:*

```
var position = job.characteristic.value.indexOf(0)
if ((position > 20) || (-1 == position))
   position = 20
_deviceID.value = String(job.characteristic.value, 0, position)
```

Comment: I think first I'd try to simplify it by using `dropLastWhile` which is taking a predicate for Char, so you can skip a lot manual stuff. you can `dropLastWhile` the characters are not alphanumeric. (or you can `takeWhile` they are)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a bug in `dropLast()`. Your `tempBytes` is of size `30`, but in `dropLast` you subtract `index` from `20`, not from `30`. This is why it is usually better to use constants or reference the collection size directly:

```
tempBytes.toString(Charsets.ISO_8859_1).dropLast(tempBytes.size - index)
```

Also, there is no need to use `dropLast()` if we need first `n` items, because `take()` does exactly this:

```
tempBytes.toString(Charsets.ISO_8859_1).take(index)
```

But honestly, your code is pretty overcomplicated. You can achieve a similar effect by replacing your whole code with simply:

```
val newString = String(bytes, 0, bytes.indexOf(0))
```

There are some differences comparing to your code, e.g. it searches past index 20 and it requires a null-byte somewhere. Depending on your specific case it may need to be adjusted.